# Session lost, when fetch data with react from PHP API

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, typescript, session

When I use fetch() in react and print the session ID of my PHP Server, it always gets a new ID.

My Code looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchConfig = async () => {
      const data = await (
        await fetch(apiPath, {
          credentials: "include",
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            action: "getConfig",
          }),
        })
      ).json();

      console.log(data);
    };

    fetchConfig();
  }, []);
```

My PHP-Code looks like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents("php://input")));
    $return = array();

    $return["sessionID"] = session_id();


    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

request-headers

-> in chrome:

```
:Authority: <<MY SERVER>>
:Method: POST
:Path: <<MY API PATH>>
:Scheme: https
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:5173
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:5173/
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

-> in firefox:

```
POST <<MY API PATH>> HTTP/2
Host: <<MY SERVER>>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:5173/
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 22
Origin: http://localhost:5173
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=<<SESSIONID>>
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
TE: trailers
```

If I open the api-Path in a seperate window, the session ID is always the same until I clear the cookies. So there must be somthing wrong in my fetch call.

EDIT: I noticed, in firefox, there is no problem with the session ID. Maybe because firefox is sending a Cookie with "PHPSESSID"? How can i solve this in chrome?

EDIT 2: I found out, that you have to specify the SameSite attribute for chrome, if I want to send a cookie in a cross-site context. What do I have to do so? How can I modfy an existing cookie in my fetch request?

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: can you verify in the browser developer tools that the session cookie is being sent in the request - note: `open the api-Path in a seperate window` is a GET request, but you are performing a POST request in this code, so, without seeing the PHP, it could be server code that is at fault

Comment: I updated the question so you can see the PHP-Code.

Comment: you seemed to have missed the first part of my comment - probably the most important part TBH

Comment: Im not sure about that. You can see my request-header above now.

Comment: I take it chrome (either googles chrome or microsofts chrome) doesn't show what cookies are being sent in a request. That's not helpful. Try firefox, at least you'll be able to see if the session cookie is being sent

Comment: Hmm thats weird. In Firefox i have no problems anymore. The session ID is now the same in every request. It seems to be a Chrome-Problem?

Comment: "a chrome problem" - like "wet water" or "blue sky" really. Google seem to think they control the world wide web and their "browser" defines how it should work - more often than not, they are wrong